# Prepare JSON string to post data to a RESTful webservice

Tags: apex, json

I am doing a callout to RESTful web service and following the [example](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/integration_workbook.pdf) given here in [Integration workbook](https://gist.github.com/tyoshikawa1106/e9ea9757381ddfac865e)

My actual requirement is to query for some values and post these values in JSON to webservice.

1) To prepare JSON, I see 2 options: JSONGenerator and Serialize. The difference I noted among them is I can format JSON structure in JSON Generator. Is there any other major difference like size of the JSON etc.

2) While using JsonGenerator, I can write my own field labels in JSON using `writeStringField` but If I am going for serialize, I need to declare all field labels with the datatype they are supposed to hold in a separate class. Is it also necessary to declare a separate class to hold these field labels while using JSONGenerator ?

3) Since I am posting values to external webservice, should I use `{get;set;}`

Thanks

Comment: others will give longer answer, but `No` to #3

Comment: The generator allows for more precise control and for my purposes at least is overly complex for most tasks. Serializing a class is much easier and quicker. There are limitations on the class though like the inability to use certain property names etc. Class is also easier to maintain and update. I would say go class/serialize first and if that presents roadblocks then use the generator. and no to #2 it is not necessary to use a class with the generator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making comment an answer. If someone wants to add a more elaborate answer......

The generator allows for more precise control and for my purposes at least is overly complex for most tasks.

Serializing a class is much easier and quicker.

There are limitations on the class though like the inability to use certain property names etc.

Class is also easier to maintain and update.

I would say go class/serialize first and if that presents roadblocks then use the generator. and no to #2 it is not necessary to use a class with the generator